# How can I calculate the percentage change of a serie in DAX Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I want to calculate the monthly change of this serie which is already on a monthly basis. So my question is how I could calculate the change for each row (starting from the second row).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create this one measure:

```
% Change = 
VAR thisDate = MAX('Table'[Datum])
VAR previousDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[Datum]),
        'Table'[Datum] < thisDate
    )
VAR thisPrice = MAX('Table'[Omifx])
VAR previousPrice = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[Omifx]),
        'Table'[Datum] = previousDate
    )
RETURN 
    IF(
        NOT ISBLANK(previousPrice),  
        DIVIDE(
             thisPrice - previousPrice,
             previousPrice
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. I just used FILTER instead of CALCULATE which is much smarter to use in this case.

Comment: FILTER() returns **tables**, but here we need **scalars** as returned from CALCULATE()

Answer (score 0):

the proper way of doing it is as follows:

1. Create the following **DAX Table**:

```
    Calendar_Table = 
    var startyear = year(min(datatable[Datum]))
    var endyear = year(max(datatable[Datum]))
    var result =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            CALENDAR(DATE(startyear, 1, 1), DATE(endyear, 12, 31)),
            "Calendar Year", YEAR([Date]),
            "Month Name Short", FORMAT( [Date], "mmm" ),
            "Month Order", FORMAT( [Date], "mm" )
        )
    return result
```

2. create a data model by linking [Date] column in calendar_table with [Datum] column
3. create the following **DAX Measure**

```
Previous Day Total = 
  CALCULATE( 
    sum(datetable[Omifx]), 
    DATEADD('Date Table'[Date], -1, DAY) 
  )
```

4. create a new DAX Measure

```
    Change = sum(datatable[Omifx]) - [Previous Day Total]
```

there is more in the blog post: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/almost-everything-you-need-to-know-about-dates-in-power-bi-2f24c64c5671